# Python "list out of the range"

Tags: python

estou tentando colocar duas colunas de dados, cada uma em um arquivo diferente com os nomes que vocês verão no código, em um só arquivo como duas colunas lado a lado. O erro, citado no título ("list out of the range") sempre aparece onde indicarei com um asterisco no código. Podem me ajudar?

Normalmente esse erro aparece quando chamo um dado que não está num vetor ou ultrapassa o tamanho do vetor (???acho???) mas no caso estou criando um vetor e atribuindo dados a ele ne. No caso uma matriz mesmo.
* já tentei fazer so somando os valores (ex. a+b) pra ver se os dois ficavam um do lado do outro como uma concatenação de um texto e não deu certo, ai nao sei mais. Fui tentar isso de matriz e não consegui tbm enfim... me ajudem!

```
arquivo1 = open ("bandaIZ_coluna5_dados_não_saturados.txt","r")
dados1 = arquivo1.readlines()
arquivo1.close()
arquivo2 = open ("bandaIZ_coluna13_dados_não_saturados.txt","r")
dados2 = arquivo2.readlines()
arquivo2.close()
arquivo3 = open ("bandaIZ_colunas13&5","w")
if(len(dados1) == len(dados2)):
    print("len(dados1) == len(dados2)")
i = 0
d = []
while(i < len(dados1)):
    d2 = (dados2[i])
    d1 = (dados1[i])
    d[i][0] = d2
    d[i][1] = d1  
    i=i+1
arquivo3.write(d)
arquivo3.close()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Há alguns problemas no seu código:

1. A função `write` espera apenas uma `string` como parâmetro. Se desejas escrever vários itens de uma vez, utilize a função `writelines`, que aceita uma lista de `string` como parâmetro.
2. Você está tentando atribuir um valor à uma posição inexistente da lista (`d[i][0] = d2`). Como comentado na [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/190712/5878), você pode utilizar o `append`.

   2.1.  Aproveita e faz a concatenação antes. Diminui a complexidade do código.

Veja:

```
i = 0
d = []

while(i < len(dados1)):
    # O [:-1] retira o \n do final
    d2 = dados2[i][:-1]
    d1 = dados1[i][:-1]
    d.append("{} {}\n".format(d2, d1))
    i=i+1

arquivo3.writelines(d)
```

---

Se preferir uma solução mais *pythonica*:

```py
with open("bandaIZ_coluna5_dados_não_saturados.txt", "r") as file:
    dados1 = [i[:-1] for i in file.readlines()]

with open("bandaIZ_coluna13_dados_não_saturados.txt", "r") as file:
    dados2 = [i[:-1] for i in file.readlines()]

# Nome do arquivo está estranho
with open("bandaIZ_colunas13&5", "w") as file:
    file.writelines(["{} {}\n".format(a, b) for a, b in zip(dados2, dados1)])
```

Com a utilização de `with`, não precisamos nos preocupar em fechar o arquivo. Para cada um, lemos o conteúdo e armazenamos o valor de cada linha, excluindo o último caractere, referente ao `\n`. É feito isso através de uma compressão de lista:

```
dados = [i[:-1] for i in file.readlines()]
```

Ao fim, escreve a concatenação dos valores no terceiro arquivo. A concatenação é feita através de uma compressão de lista e a função [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip), nativa do Python.

---

Se os arquivos de entrada forem:

*Arquivo 1*

```
a
b
c
d
```

*Arquivo 2*

```
e
f
g
h
```

O arquivo final será:

```
e a
f b
g c
h d
```

Comment: Nossa, eu te amo! 
Entendi o código e muito obrigado. Vou treinar mais. :)

Comment: Será que poderia me auxiliar no conceito de "pythonico" e onde eu posso aprender mais desses padrões no Python? Já ouvi termos parecidos algumas vezes.

Comment: @Vinicius, o conceito "pythonico" consiste em escrever o código fazendo uso das ferramentas que o Python possui e não apenas aplicar vícios de outras linguagens. O uso de `for/while` é um dos principais exemplos. Quem vem de outra para linguagem para o Python tem o costume de utilizá-los quando trabalha com vetores, mas quase sempre existe uma maneira mais simples de se fazer com Python do que escrever o `for/while`, tal como a compressão de listas.

Comment: Perfeito, vou dar uma lida na documentação sobre listas. Valeu. :-)

Comment: @Vinicius, você pode dar uma lida na PEP8, que define algumas convenções de estilo e pode pesquisar na web por *beautiful python* ou *idiomatic python*. Esse [vídeo](https://youtu.be/OSGv2VnC0go) do Raymond Hettinger (colaborador do Python) é um belo exemplo.

Answer (score 0):

Como voce mesmo declarou, d é uma lista, mas voce jamais coloca nada nela. Mesmo assim, dentro do seu loop, voce tenta acessar os elementos d[i], e por isso ocorre um erro.

O que voce provavelmente quer fazer é:

```
d.append([d2,d1])
```

Além disso, o argumento de write é str, nao lista. Para colocar em arquivo o conteudo da sua lista, voce provavelmente ira querer fazer:

```
for item in d:
    arquivo3.write(str(item[0]) + str(item[1]))
```

Comment: o "arquivo3.write" não recebe uma lista. É o que meu programa fala. "write() argument must be str, not list"

Comment: na realidade é o contrario, o argumento que voce deu é uma lista, mas o argumento correto é do tipo str. Editei a resposta pra conter essa informação.

Answer (score 0):

Em Python, uma lista é representada como uma sequência de objetos separados por vírgula e dentro de colchetes [], assim, uma lista vazia, por exemplo, pode ser representada por colchetes sem nenhum conteúdo. A Listagem 1 mostra algumas possibilidades de criação desse tipo de objeto.

```
>>> lista = [] 
>>> lista
[]
>>> lista = ['O carro','peixe',123,111]
>>> lista
['O carro', 'peixe', 123, 111]
>>> nova_lista = ['pedra',lista]
>>> nova_lista
['pedra', ['O carro', 'peixe', 123, 111]]
```

- Linhas 1 a 3: Declaração de uma lista sem nenhum elemento e sua impressão, que apresenta apenas os colchetes, indicando que a lista está vazia;
- Linhas 4 a 6: Atribuição de duas strings e dois inteiros à variável lista e sua posterior impressão;
- Linhas 7 a 9: Criação e impressão da variável nova_lista, que é inicializada com a string 'pedra', e uma outra lista.

As possibilidades de declaração e atribuição de valores a uma lista são várias, e a opção por uma ou outra dependerá do contexto e aplicação.

**Operadores de lista**

A linguagem Python dispõe de vários métodos e operadores para auxiliar na manipulação de listas. O primeiro e mais básico é o operador de acesso aos seus itens a partir dos índices. Para compreendê-lo, é importante entender como os dados são armazenados nessa estrutura, o que é ilustrado na Figura 1.

[image: Representação de uma lista e os índices dos elementos]

A lista representada nessa figura é composta por quatro elementos, cujos índices variam de zero a três. Por exemplo, o primeiro objeto, no índice 0, é a string 'O carro'. Tendo em mente essa organização interna, podemos acessar cada um dos elementos utilizando a sintaxe lista[índice], como mostra a Listagem 2.

Veja mais neste [curso de python](https://www.devmedia.com.br/curso/curso-python/2280).